# Repository pattern how to define an OrderBy

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a repository class that is very generic in its use and doesn't refer to my tables specifically. Shown below is one of the functions to get all the items in a table. What I would like to do is to extend this so that the result can be ordered. Is there a way to pass in a predicate / expression or something similar?

```
public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class
{
    return _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `Queryable.OrderBy` method on your all entities:

```
fooRepository.All().OrderBy(foo => foo.Bar)
```

If you want to add method with predicate:

```
public IQueryable<T> AllOrderedBy<T,TKey>(Expression<Func<T,TKey>> predicate) 
    where T : class
{
    return _context.Set<T>().OrderBy(predicate);
}
```

BTW `DbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`, so you don't need to call `AsQueryable()`.

Comment: Repository should not be returning `IQueryable`